# Есть ли более подходящее решение проблемы с созависимостью 2 классов?

Tags: javascript, ооп, typescript, архитектура, проектирование

Есть ситуация, где один класс хранит в себе поля 2 экземпляров классов, которые передаются друг другу в конструкторе, от чего ни один ни второй создать не выходит:

```
class A{
    private readonly _instance: B;

    constructor(instance: B){
        this._instance = instance;
    }
}

class B{
    private readonly _instance: A;

    constructor(instance: A){
        this._instance = instance;
    }
}

class C{
    private readonly _a: A;
    private readonly _b: B;

    constructor(){
        // this._a = new A(this._b)
        // this._b = new B(this._a)
    }
}
```

Чтобы создать экземпляр класса A, нужно прежде создать экземпляр класса B, который в свою очередь требует экземпляр класса A и так по кругу.

Есть такой вариант решения:

```
class A{
    private readonly _instanceCallback: () => B;

    constructor(instanceCallback: () => B){
        this._instanceCallback = instanceCallback;
    }

    private get _instance(): B{
        return this._instanceCallback();
    }
}

class B{
    private readonly _instanceCallback: () => A;

    constructor(instanceCallback: () => A){
        this._instanceCallback = instanceCallback;
    }

    private get _instance(): A{
        return this._instanceCallback();
    }
}

class C{
    private readonly _a: A;
    private readonly _b: B;

    constructor(){
        this._a = new A(() => this._b)
        this._b = new B(() => this._a)
    }
}
```

Только такое решение вызывает сомнения. Возможно есть какие-то ещё варианты

Comment: Лучше опиши задачу полностью, что ты пытаешься решить.  Потому что вызова классов друг в друге быть не должно и ты заведомо на ложном пути.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский
Есть 3 класса: Page - собирательный (тот же C); Invoker - выполняющий команды; UIManager - отвечающий за элементы интерфейса.
Invoker когда выполняет команды может вносить изменения в некоторые элементы интерфейса (стили и т.п.) и поэтому ему нужно иметь доступ к UIManager.
UIManager в свою очередь при инициализации элементов интерфейса устанавливает действия при событиях. То есть, при нажатии на кнопку, к примеру, нужно вызывать метод из Invoker'а.

Comment: Если тут строится своего рода иерархия элемнетов, то тут должно быть, я думаю базовый класс "HTMLElement", от которого наследуются другие. Эти элементы в себе должны сами содержать логику отрисовки и выполнения действий над собой...сама иерархия подчиняется шаблону проектирования "Composite (Компоновщик)"...Всё равно из представленого условия не ясно что именно проектируется.... Если аналог React - с работой над DOM деревом - это одно, если какая-то форма с калькулятором продутктов - это другое.....Одно можно точно сказать: делать Менеджеры и там и там, где огромный список данных - некорректно

Comment: То есть когда я писал *"опиши задачу полностью, что ты пытаешься решить"* --- я не имел в виду описать какие классы у тебя есть и как ты их между собой хочешь связать, а **глобально** какую задачу решаешь. react свой пишешь или что

Comment: Ещё, если разделять прям на два раздельных GOD класса, то можно сделать проще: события. Менеджер с событиями :DDD  UIManager подписывается на события, а Invoker генерирует событие с данными. (можно применить шаблон проектирования Observer.... но не обязательно)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский UIManager - это собирательный класс, который в себе содержит несколько HTML элементов (уже готовых, он всего лишь предоставляет метод их добавления на страницу когда нужно и объект в поле, для их хранения).
Проще говоря, проектируется страница сайта-визуализатора и её компоненты (там нет перехода по ссылкам, страницы хранятся в JS и по ним просто происходит переход с помощью вызова в них соответствующего метода select).
"глобально какую задачу решаешь" - сайт-визуализатор пишется, где происходят анимации, которой можно управлять

Comment: Избавьтесь от `readonly`, соединяйте объекты через сеттеры.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy то есть? Создать публичный сеттер и через него в собирательном классе (C) присваивать объект, после того как нужный объект будет создан?

Comment: Чтобы на практике избежать таких "академических проблем" используют разного рода шаблонные подходы (устоявшиеся приемы проектирования структуры кода). Посмотрите на MVC (сильно напоминает то, что вы описали в комментарии) и Observer как механизм развязывания сильной связанности объектов, которые, тем не менее, должны как-то взаимодействовать